# Image Overlay with CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'll try and be brief - we have a slider on our website and when we upload the images the text on the slider is difficult to read, so we figured out that if we added a white overlay in photoshop to the picture, the slider looks much better.

However, this is not a great solution because once the post moves to the general column, we find that the image with the overlay by photoshop is now not as appealing to the eye.

The solution that was asked ,was can we add a semi-transparent overlay to the div that holds the slider, so that way any image uploaded will have that semi transparent overlay only in the slider.

I did some research on here and other sites working with overlay and css - and have worked it into a set where I'm almost there but am missing some fundamental pieces I think.

Right now its working on hover only, so I need to figure that out, but if you see the example you'll understand

In my utopia - if I click on RUN on jsfiddle, that image should have the overlay on it already, not on hover and I think I'm missing where I'm supposed to make edits

http://jsfiddle.net/9LXcU/

```
.box { 
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
    height:151px;
    width:195px;

}
.overlay {  
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, .75);
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0;    
    width:100%;height:100%; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.box:hover {
    border:1px solid #555;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.box:hover .overlay {
    opacity:12;
}
.search {
    position:relative;
    top:60px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `:hover` in your CSS if you don't want hover behavior? Also the maximum value for `opacity` is 1.

Comment: i was using tutorials from different sites to help me get started, the ones i was using were using overlays on hover, i know that is part of what i have to get rid of, but when i remove hover, the overlay div never shows, so i'm trying to find out how to just have it there permanently - which is why i stated that i know i have edits to make, i'm just trying different things on jsfiddle and maybe i can get direction on a line of action from the community

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9LXcU/1/ ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant - I'm not going to bother you to ask what you did because I want to see the diff in your post and my original code to try and learn it - but thank you! That was exactly what I was meaning lol

Comment: and I meant "not going to bother you" because I always feel awkward asking questions on sites like this because Im old and from the days of IRC where "find it yourself before you ask" was the guideline lol - your example was VERY appreciated Josiah :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9LXcU/7/) that may be what you want.

CSS

```
.box { 
  border:1px solid #000;
  padding:5px;
  height:151px;
  width:195px;
  text-align:center;
  background: url('http://www.breastcanceranswers.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/featuredimagebcam.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```